# How can I activate master workbook and bring it to the front of all open excel files?

Tags: excel, vba

This code is opening a set of workbooks and works fine for that. However, after the workbooks have been opened, I want the master workbook, from where I run the macro, to be activate and brought to the front.
Here's my code and it does not activate and bring the master excel file to the front.

```
    Sub SkipBlankCells2()
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, FName As String
Set rng = Range("E12:E24")

'Disable Screen Updating - stop screen flickering
'   And Disable Events to avoid inturupted dialogs / popups
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Application.DefaultFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

For Each cel In rng
    If Len(cel) >= 1 Then
            FName = cel.Value
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName
    End If
Next cel

'Enable Screen Updating and Events
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    'Return to master workbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need all the workbooks to stay open? You could work them, close and leave only the master open. But  `.Activate` should work.

Comment: and how do you determine which one is the master workbook?

Comment: Yeah - I need for the workbooks to stay open as I will (1) do a Monte Carlo simulation involving all of them and (2) copy the results over to the master workbook. Thanks.

Comment: The master workbook holds the macros.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that (suggestion by JvdV) but it didn't make any difference. The workbook from where I run the macro ends up being in the back after I've opened the other workbooks (2 in my test case).

Comment: Strange behavior.May check for Activate / Deactivate (or other) events of workbooks (windows) in master or other open workbooks. May also check for `windowstate`  to `xlMinimized`